# How to append text to a text file in C++ without delete the data in file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to append text to a text file in C++ without delete the data in file 
ex
in the file data like hello 
and when i open this file and write world 
the file will be like hello world

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are used to read/write a file using "fstream"

If "input.txt" has the contents below

```
Hello
```

If you run the simple codes below,

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("input.txt", std::ios::out|std::ios::app);
    ofs << "\nWorld";
    ofs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

You can see the result text file below

```
Hello
World
```

`ios::out` is set to write mode

`ios::app` append the data at the end of the file.

---

I modified your code a little.
The process is stopped If you type "exit" when you type your name.

```
#include<string> 
#include<iostream> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    std::string data; 
    std::string data2; 
    std::string data3; 
    std::ofstream ofs; 
    ofs.open("input.txt", std::ios::out|std::ios::app); 
    cout<<"plz enter ur name "; 
    cout<<"plz enter ur age "; 
    cout<<"plz enter ur country"; 

    while (std::getline(std::cin, data) && data!="exit")
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, data2);
        std::getline(std::cin, data3);
        ofs << data << "\t" << data2 << "\t" << data3 << endl;
    }
    ofs.close(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: thanks . I write code to take from user name and age and country and when u close the file and write again the old data will stay in the file but i have some error can u help me to correct it ?

Comment: @yeungah Could you give me your code and error messages?

Comment: `#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 std::string data;
 std::string data2;
 std::string data3;
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("input.txt", std::ios::out|std::ios::app);
 cout<<"plz enter ur name ";
 cout<<"plz enter ur age ";
 cout<<"plz enter ur country";
 do{ std::getline(std::cin,data);
 std::getline(std::cin,data2);
 std::getline(std::cin,data3);
 if(data!="exit")
    ofs << data<<"\t"<<data2<<"\t"<<data3;
 ofs<<endl;
 }
 while(data!="exit");
    ofs.close();
    return 0;
}`

Comment: when i write exit doesn't exit from program, and i want write to file in  form NAME   AGE   COUNTRY . and if there is no data in the file, any data begins by writing from the first line and then when adding new data, it is written from the second line and so on. If there is data from a previous one, write it from the next line

Comment: @yeungah I gave you some idea using the modified code. Please check the revised text above my answer.

Comment: kamahmnida ^.^. I have only question if i want when the msg plz enter ur name after msg the user write his name ans so on . i try to do this but i failed ...